# Type mismatch error when adding Label to Scala Swing Panel

Tags: java, swing, scala, jpanel, label

I have this Class extending `FlowPanel` and I'm trying to add Labels into it:

```scala
import java.awt.{Label, Color}
import scala.swing._
import scala.util.Random    

class MyPanel extends FlowPanel{
  val dimension = new Dimension(600,400)
  maximumSize = dimension
  minimumSize = dimension
  preferredSize = dimension
  foreground = Color.white
  background = Color.LIGHT_GRAY

  def drowLabels(size: Int) = {
    for(i <- 0 until size){
      contents += new Label()
      revalidate();
      repaint();
    }
  }
```

But I get an error message:

```
type mismatch;
found   : java.awt.Label
required: scala.swing.Component
    contents += new Label()
                ^
```

But for example if I change `new Label()` to `new Button()`, everything works fine. Actually I can't add `Label` to any kind of container, there are always some errors.

I have been trying to find answer for an hour, but without succeed.

Comment: Not a scala developer but be aware that `java.awt.Label` is not a SWING component but AWT's. The SWING label is [javax.swing.JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html). I think the message is telling you that a SWING component is expected which `java.awt.Label` is not, but I might be wrong of course.

Comment: OMG I'm so blind. This is what happened when you let IDE add import automatically without checking it by yourself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome :) No worries, it happens all the time to everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the message is telling you that a SWING component is expected which `java.awt.Label` is not (look at your imports). The SWING label is [javax.swing.JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html), so fixing the imports as follows should solve your problem:

```
import java.awt.Color
import javax.swing.JLabel
import scala.swing._
import scala.util.Random

class MyPanel extends FlowPanel {
    ...
    def drowLabels(size: Int) = {
        for(i <- 0 until size){
            contents += new JLabel()
            revalidate();
            repaint();
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the above solution no longer works: scala swing containers will not allow you to add elements unless they inherit from `scala.swing.Component` class. Therefore, one has to either use components from scala swing or wrap Java components with `Component.wrap(javaSwingComponent)` call.

See this [question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558983/type-mismatch-error-when-adding-jlabel-jpanel-to-scala-swing-panel).